# How can I use std::regular/std::totally_ordered in C++20?

Tags: c++, std, c++20

I want to declare `template(std::regular N, std::regular E)` in my class but an error "No type named 'regular' in namespace std" is reported. The same error happened on `std::totally_ordered`. I have checked the cppreference and included the required head file `concepts` in my code but doesn't work. What happened here and what should I do? I am very new to C++, thankssss for the help.

Comment: Maybe share some actual code you have trouble with to answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

The error sounds like your compiler has not been told to compile in C++20 mode. Usually this is achieved with `--std=c++20` (linux compilers) or `/std:c++20` (MSVC) on the command line, or by configuring your build system to do this for you. Just to provide an example, something [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/q15hevac3) will then work:

```
#include <concepts>

template<std::regular N, std::regular E>
struct foo
{
    N n {};
    E e {};

    friend bool operator==(foo const&, foo const&) = default;
};

int main() 
{
    return foo{2, 1u} == foo{1, 2u};
}
```